# Was there an evil version of Dark Hawk? Not one from the future, but a bad guy with a whole other amulet?

Tags: marvel, character-identification

The Marvel 90s character **Dark Hawk** was pretty "Spider-man-esque" in terms of story; a high school kid, Chris Powell, gets super powers by accident, in the form of an alien amulet which grants him a super durable android body with Spidey-level strength, Capt America speed, stamina and senses, force blasts, an energy shield, a grapple claw, and flight.

[image]

Hr proved a fairly effective hero, helping out bigger names like Spider-Man himself, Iron Man, the New Warriors, and the West Coast Avengers at one point. I remember him facing off against another being who had armor *similar* to his, but damaged and cobbled together (torso and helmet like Dark Hawk's, but green, his amulet was removed and he had a cyber arm), but he specifically *mentioned* a character, Evil Hawk, in one book.

Is this the same character, or are they different? (As stated, this character's amulet was gone, so it's unlikely.)

Is there a scan of this Evil Hawk anywhere? What is his origin and how is he connected to Dark Hawk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are two separate characters:

- The first character you're thinking of - with the cobbled together armor - was Charles Little Sky, aka [Portal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal_(comics)). He's not connected to Darkhawk, except for the armor that he obtained from an alien named Kistur/ [Overhawk](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Kistur_(Earth-616)).
- The second character, [Evilhawk](https://www.marvel.com/characters/evilhawk), was an "extraterrestrial crime-lord" named Dargin Bokk. I believe he was responsible for the creation of the Darkhawk android. I never actually read that far in the series. He appears to have been  featured on the covers of issues [24](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Darkhawk_Vol_1_24) and [41](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Darkhawk_Vol_1_41).

Please note that this origin story was retconned in [War of Kings](https://www.marvel.com/comics/events/276/war_of_kings), and that Evilhawk never existed. I believe the entire Evilhawk incident was just imagined by Powell. The new origin was based around an organization called [The Fraternity of Raptors](https://www.marvel.com/teams-and-groups/the-fraternity-of-raptors).

Comment: How'd they manage to retcon the whole story? Reality shift? Darkhawk's encountering Ocsh, struggling with Evilhawk, etc. was all just a dream? Or did the writers just act like it had never happened and gave no explanation?

Comment: I think, based on what I've read, it's the "everything you know is wrong" sort of retcon where all of that backstory was just a hallucination.